# Using Categorical Variables for locations as an additional regressor to the Prophet model

Tags: python, time-series, prediction, facebook-prophet

I am currently trying to estimate the ridership counts for a few selected locations. Say, I have 3 bus stops labeled `A,B,C`. On the one hand, I can obviously create 3 separate Prophet models to predict each location individually. On the other hand, I wonder if I could use one-hot encoding for the labels, and then pass the encoded values as a new regressor(via

```
m.add_regressor()
```

to the Prophet model to have a single model, instead of 3 to predict the ridership at each location. This would imply that I would also need to pass the encoded category along with the future date for the prediction.

If I am wrong, I would be glad to hear if there's a different approach to using multiple geographical locations in a single model or if it is actually unrealistic.

Comment: I also have this question. Did you manage to find an approach that works?

Comment: @Urizen I opted to be using 3 different models instead.  I came to conclusion that using one-hot encoding might lead to incorrect results. I believe the main reason is that the extra regressors should be time series as well(say weather pattern, etc) and a series of 0s and 1s in (kind-of) random order would be detrimental for model's performance(as there's no underlying distribution to estimate after all). Hope this clarifies things for you.